# C# TcpClient - What's the best way for a client to determine if remote server has gracefully shutdown connection?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcpclient

I know there are various suggested ways to achieve this, using Poll/Available/Send, etc., but none of them seem to work for me. I have a connection to a remote server, which the remote server gracefully disconnects after a specific message. I need to ensure I don't disconnect from the remote server myself, and wait for the server to shutdown connection before I can safely reconnect and **send** other follow-up messages.

I'm using the ReadAsync method on Stream to get responses from that connection, as below:

```
while (await TcpClientObject.GetStream().ReadAsync(bufferData, 0, bufferData.Length) > 0)
{
     //My logic here to handle responses
}
```

What's the most recommended approach for me to verify that the remote server has gracefully shutdown the connection before attempting a reconnect? Thanks.

Comment: The TCP stack in the O/S handles disconnection already, there is very little you can do to change how it works.  Bear in mind that, certainly with async functions, things will happen when you aren't looking.   e.g. you can't check for a connection before sending or receiving data, because a disconnect may happen after you have checked.

Comment: When one side closes its sending part of the connection, it can still receive data from the other end. So on the client side here you won't receive data after receiving a disconnect, and you can still send data as long as the server side is prepared to handle it.

Comment: The keep alive option is meant for the purpose.  When a client uses Keep-Alive a packet with zero bytes is sent from client to server periodically.  Then when a ACK is not received from the server it indicates the connection is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If everything goes well `ReadAsync` will return 0 when the server closes the connection.

An exception is thrown if your side detects an abnormal disconnection, but in the worst case your end still thinks it's connected and `ReadAsync` won't return.

Comment: You will only fail is data is sent.  If a client is not sending this will not work.